# Extract a video from an SWF file

Tags: video, flash, movie

I want to extract a video from an swf file and make from it a video to load to youtube(I lost the origianl videos).

The swf was created with flash 5-8(not sure which. how can I check if it is importent?).

When I looked at the source(I don't have the fla) with Sothink SWF Quicker I could export the sound but not the video.

What I did see was that the video was without sound(wierd but true).

can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Trillix](http://www.decompiler-swf.com/swf-decompiler-mac/).  You should be able to extract your assets.